# How do I make a dict subclass json serializable?

Tags: json, python-3.x, subclass

I can represent the my `Simple_Dict_Subclass` and `List_Subclass` with `json.dumps`, but not `Custom_Dict_Subclass`. When `json.dumps` is called on `List_Subclass` its `__iter__` method is called, so I reasoned that `json.dumps` would call a dictionary's `items` method. And `items` is called in `Simple_Dict_Subclass` but not `Custom_Dict_Subclass`. How can I make my `Custom_Dict_Subclass` `json` serializable like `Simple_Dict_Subclass`?

```
import json

class Custom_Dict_Subclass(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

    def items(self):
        print("'Items' called from Custom_Dict_Subclass")
        yield from self.data.items()

class Simple_Dict_Subclass(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super().__getitem__(key)

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()

    def items(self):
        print("'Items' called from Simple_Dict_Subclass")
        yield from super().items()

class List_Subclass(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.data[index] = value

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.data

    def append(self, value):
        self.data.append(value)

d = Custom_Dict_Subclass()
d[0] = None
print(d)             # Works
print(json.dumps(d)) # Does't work

d = Simple_Dict_Subclass()
d[0] = None
print(d)             # Works
print(json.dumps(d)) # Works

l = List_Subclass()
l.append(None)
print(l)             # Works
print(json.dumps(l)) # Works
```

Output:

```
{0: None}   # Custom dict string     working
{}          # Custom dict json.dumps not working

{0: None}   # Simple dict string     working
'Items' called from Simple_Dict_Subclass
{"0": null} # Simple dict json.dumps working

[None]      # List string            working
[null]      # List json.dumps        working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is not safe to assume that `json.dumps` will
trigger the `items` method of the dictionary.  This is how it is
implemented but you cannot rely on that.

In your case, the `Custom_Dict_Subclass.items` is never called because
(key, value) pairs are not added to the `dict` object but to its
`data` attribute.

To fix that you need to invoke the super methods in
`Custom_Dict_Subclass`:

```py
class Custom_Dict_Subclass(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        dict.__init__(self)
        self.data = {}
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

The object is dumped correctly, but of course, (key, value) will then
be stored twice: in the `dict` object and in its `data` attribute.

In that situation, it is better to define a sub class of
`json.JSONEncoder` to implement the translation of a
`Custom_Dict_Subclass` object to a json serialisable object and to
give this class as the keyword argument `cls` of `json.dumps`:

```py
import json

class Custom_Dict_Subclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

    def items(self):
        print("'Items' called from Custom_Dict_Subclass")
        yield from self.data.items()

class CustomDictEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        """called by json.dumps to translate an object obj to
        a json serialisable data"""
        if isinstance(obj, Custom_Dict_Subclass):
            return obj.data
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)  

d = Custom_Dict_Subclass()
d[0] = None
print(json.dumps(d, cls=CustomDictEncoder))
```

Comment: Hey quoify, seems like your (first) example doesn't work (python 3.9). Do you want to clear that up?

Comment: @WalterVos it works fine with python 3.11.  I cannot easily test with 3.9 right now.  Could you please explain further the problem ?

Comment: Ah, I see how you meant for your example to be used now: `cds = Custom_Dict_Subclass(); cds['key'] = 'value'; json.dumps(cds)`. It's just a shame that the constructor doesn't work then, and the call to `dict.__init__(self)` is redundant, actually. I'll offer an example where these aspects are included. Edit: I see that this comes from the OP, so I'm sorry about my downvote :(

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution of using a custom `json.JSONEncoder` is pragmatic but really just works around what IMHO looks like a bug in cpython. You are supposed to be able to subclass `dict`, right?

But the C optimised JSON encoder doesn't seem to know that. We find [this code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0fb18b02c8ad56299d6a2910be0bab8ad601ef24/Modules/_json.c#L1542):

```
    if (PyDict_GET_SIZE(dct) == 0)  /* Fast path */
        return _PyUnicodeWriter_WriteASCIIString(writer, "{}", 2);
```

`PyDict_GET_SIZE` reads directly from the native `dict` structure which isn't under your direct control. If you want an entirely custom storage like in your `Custom_Dict_Subclass` it seems like you're out of luck, at least as of Python 3.12. (Incidentally, the cpython provided `OrderedDict` subclass works okay despite this because it uses the native storage, via `super`.)

If performance is not a concern, you could simply disable the C based JSON encoder: `json.encoder.c_make_encoder = None`.

Comment: Not sure I'm right about this being a bug but I posted a bug report to cpython here: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/110941